# Defaulting all attributes to wrapper html in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Because DOM children are always accessible via their parent, I want to always apply `:class` and `:data` to the wrapper. For example,

```
<%= f.input :name, :class => :half %>
```

should produce the same output as

```
<%= f.input :name, :wrapper_html => { :class => :half } %>
```

I was hoping to change this in simple_form.rb with something like:

```
config.item_wrapper_class = :class
```

But no luck. Is the only way to achieve this via a custom builder? If so, how would I achieve this in a custom builder?

Comment: I'm curious about your motivation

Comment: There's no reason to apply a class to an input instead of its wrapper, so specifying :wrapper_html for :class is unnecessary. I am creating a styleguide for my organization and want to make the markup concise and easy for back-end engineers to implement or modify.

Comment: You would have to use a custom builder for this. Just my opinion, but I'm not sure that it's better to use a custom builder here - it's more semantically clear that the input tag is going to be wrapped and that the wrapper is going to hold the class with the way simple form works by default. I see you want to save some typing, but how much typing are you really saving? How many forms does your application have where you actually have to give each input a custom class?

Comment: @Andrew It's not about the extra typing. This is a simple example, but when you are passing more attributes to the inputs and wrappers it can be confusing. To just add a data attribute you end up nested 3 levels in.

Most inputs have a class that is either half, third, or two-thirds because it is a grid-based form design.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the inputs with a tag like so:

```
## Inputs
b.use :label
b.wrapper :default, :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |ba|
  ba.use :input
  ba.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'label label-important' }
  ba.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'p', :class => 'help-block' }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this addresses the question.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to write your own form builders to do this, and from what you've described you would like behavior that is distinct enough from simple_form that I'm not sure it makes sense to use simple_form at all- you probably just want to roll your own form builder stack.

You'll have to look up how to roll your own form builders, I haven't done that.

That said one good workaround might be, if your concern is just how to put class and data attributes on wrappers without so much nesting of hashes, you could just omit the wrappers from simple form and provide your own wrapping element directly. I think that would be cleaner if you're going to put classes etc. on each one. For instance, using haml:

```
.input.quarter{:data => { :foo => :bar }}
  = f.input :foo, :wrapper => false
```